# nodejs: how can i parse comments above methods?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I want to declare additional parameters above methods as like as in Symfony2 php-framework, they should be annotation form (with @ symbol), wrapped by comment. Something like that:

```
class SomeController {

    constructor() {
        //
    }

    /*
    * @Secure(roles="admin")
    * @Cache(smaxage="15")
    */
    indexAction() {
        //
    }

};
```

how do i do that?

Comment: And do you want to be able to read those annotations from `indexAction()`? You won't be able to because they're just comments.

Comment: @RGraham, but compiler don't think so )

Comment: The compiler completely ignores them. You'll have to either use a parser like esprima or follow the duplicate link to see the ES7 implementation of annotations